# CodeIgniter --> Cookie paths cannot contain any of the following ',; \t\r\n\013\014' /xxxxx/system/libraries/Session/Session.php 170

Tags: codeigniter

I got following error

> Cookie paths cannot contain any of the following ',; \t\r\n\013\014' /xxxxx/system/libraries/Session/Session.php 170

after setting

```
$config['cookie_path']      = '/; SameSite=Strict';
```

in config.php file. how to get rid of it?

Answer (score 1):

You can solve your issue using this metod right here: https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/issues/5791#issuecomment-798956532

More exactly you need to set this in your application/config/config.php file:

`$config['cookie_path']     = '/';`

and replace the code from system/core/Input.php file from the line 289 to 352:

```
/** 
 * Set cookie 
 * 
 * Accepts an arbitrary number of parameters (up to 7) or an associative 
 * array in the first parameter containing all the values. 
 * 
 * @param   string|mixed[]  $name       Cookie name or an array containing parameters 
 * @param   string      $value      Cookie value 
 * @param   int     $expire     Cookie expiration time in seconds 
 * @param   string      $domain     Cookie domain (e.g.: '.yourdomain.com') 
 * @param   string      $path       Cookie path (default: '/') 
 * @param   string      $prefix     Cookie name prefix 
 * @param   bool        $secure     Whether to only transfer cookies via SSL 
 * @param   bool        $httponly   Whether to only makes the cookie accessible via HTTP (no javascript) 
 * @return  void 
 */ 
public function set_cookie($name, $value = '', $expire = 0, $domain = '', $path = '/', $prefix = '', $secure = NULL, $httponly = NULL) 
{ 
    if (is_array($name)) 
    { 
        // always leave 'name' in last place, as the loop will break otherwise, due to $$item 
        foreach (array('value', 'expire', 'domain', 'path', 'prefix', 'secure', 'httponly', 'name') as $item) 
        { 
            if (isset($name[$item])) 
            { 
                $$item = $name[$item]; 
            } 
        } 
    } 

    if ($prefix === '' && config_item('cookie_prefix') !== '') 
    { 
        $prefix = config_item('cookie_prefix'); 
    } 

    if ($domain == '' && config_item('cookie_domain') != '') 
    { 
        $domain = config_item('cookie_domain'); 
    } 

    if ($path === '/' && config_item('cookie_path') !== '/') 
    { 
        $path = config_item('cookie_path'); 
    } 

    $secure = ($secure === NULL && config_item('cookie_secure') !== NULL) 
        ? (bool) config_item('cookie_secure') 
        : (bool) $secure; 

    $httponly = ($httponly === NULL && config_item('cookie_httponly') !== NULL) 
        ? (bool) config_item('cookie_httponly') 
        : (bool) $httponly; 

    if ( ! is_numeric($expire) OR $expire < 0) 
    { 
        $expire = 1; 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        $expire = ($expire > 0) ? time() + $expire : 0; 
    } 

    setcookie($prefix.$name, $value, $expire, $path, $domain, $secure, $httponly); 
}
```